# pre saved posts query from db options table

Tags: query, get-posts

I found a question about magazine style front pages that queries always only 1 post (or custom_post_types, etc.) from a whole load of different categories, tags or custom taxonomies. I thought about this for a while and came with something like this as a start.

```
function pre_saved_posts() {
    if (
        ! is_admin()
        OR ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )
    )
        return;

    global $post;

    // Option-Name
    $opt_name = 'theme_post_ids';
    // get data from DB
    $db_option_value = get_option( $opt_name );
    // If there's nothing in the DB, create an array, else add the ID to the array of post_IDs
    empty( $db_option_value ) ? $post_ids = array( $post->ID ) : $post_ids .= $post->ID;

    // get posts
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'include' => $post_ids ) );

    // DB-Option @Option-Table updaten or add
    empty( $db_option_value ) ? add_option( $opt_name, $posts ) : update_option( $opt_name, $posts );
}
// Do it when a post is updated
add_action( 'save_post', 'pre_saved_posts', 20 );
```

Would be displayed like this:

```
$some_posts = get_option( 'theme_post_ids' );
foreach ( $some_posts as $post )
{
    // possible for ex.: $post->ID, $post->post_content, $post->post_title, etc.
}
```

It's not tested and only an example, but maybe there's someone interested in extending this. I still question myself how much sense it makes, but i could imagine that there's one large multidimensional array that contains subarrays for different requests ex.

```
$some_posts = get_option( 'theme_post_ids' ); $home_posts = $someposts['home'];
```

If this would be stored in a `global $var`, maybe there could be some performance increase.

Ideas/Suggestions/Whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@kaiser:**

Consider using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) instead, that's what it is built for.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: ehm... yea. completely forgot about this. never used it :) and i already updated my answer at the forum. thanks